# Document Footer from Template

Tags: c#, ms-word, styles

I have a Word document which I want to attach an existing template to.

In order the template styles will be set as the document styles I have to update the styles.

All templates definitions are successfully updated except the footer of the template.

```
//Opening the document to Word application  

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
object oFileName= MyDocumentPath;  
wordDoc= wordApp.Documents.Open(ref oFileName,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing,  ref missing);  

//Use an existing template  

object oTemplate = (object)coverPagePath;                   
wordApp.ActiveDocument.set_AttachedTemplate(ref oTemplate);                 
wordApp.ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles();
```

Any ideas?